# specifying properties of relations in alloy

Tags: alloy

I am trying to express certain mathematical properties of relations in Alloy, but I am not sure if I have the right approach yet, as I am just a beginner. Would appreciate any insights from the community of experts out there!

**Specifying the fact that domain of a relation as singleton**. e.g. Is the following a reasonable and correct way to do that?

```
pred SingletonDomain(r: univ->univ) {
 one ~r
}

sig S2 {}
sig S1 {
 child: set S2
}

fact {
  SingletonDomain [child]
}
```

or should it be something like the following

```
pred SingletonDomain (r: univ->univ) {
  #S2.~r = 1
}
```

This is not very modular since the use of S2 is very specific to the particular signature.

**Specifying the fact that a relation is a total order.** At the moment I am using the following, basically I am simulating xor

```
pred total[r: univ->univ] {
  all disj e, e': Event | (e.r = e' and e'.r != e) or (e.r != e' and e'.r = e)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: pred irreflexive[r: univ->univ] {
    no r & iden
}

pred acyclic[r: univ ->univ] {
   no ^r & iden
}


pred transitive[r: univ-> univ] {
   r = ^r
}

pred total[r: univ->univ] {
  all disj e, e':univ | (e.r = e' and e'.r != e) or (e.r != e' and e'.r = e)
}


pred SingletonDomain(r: univ->univ) {
      one univ.~r
}

sig S2 {rel:    set S2}
sig S1 {child: set S2}


fact {
    total[^rel] and irreflexive[rel] and transitive[rel] and SingletonDomain[child]
}

pred show {
}


run show for 4 but 2 S1

Answer (score 3):

To specify the fact that the domain of a  given relation is a singleton, your first attempt is really close to do the trick. The only problem is that `one ~r` enforces the inverse of the r relation (and thus the r relation itself) to be composed of a single tuple. This is not what you want to express.
What you want to express is that all elements in the range of the r relation have the same (so only one) image through its inverse relation '.
You should thus write the following predicate :

```
pred SingletonDomain(r: univ->univ) {
   one univ.~r
}
```

For your second question, your predicate doesn't handle cases were `e -> e' -> e '' -> e.` To handle those, you can use transitive closure.

Comment: The singleton domain works as expected! I tried the total order and a few other relations and I tried to get Alloy to generate an instance that satisfy the constraints of totality and single domain as follows, but not sure why this doesnt work

Comment: the problem comes from your total predicate. You are quantifying over univ, saying that any two elements of univ should be related by your total relation (this includes in your case S1 and S2 elements ...).

Comment: indeed. Is there a way to specify quantification over the domain and range of the relation (only defined for S2->S2) passed as an argument ? I'd like to reuse the total predicate for a several different relations defined over different domains.

Comment: Yes. You can quantify over any expressions. In order to quantify over the domain of relation r, you could thus write :  all disj e, e':univ.~r |